# Show that $\dim(\operatorname{ran}(T))=\dim( \operatorname{ran}(T^∗))$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

My question is :

> If $T \in B_{00}(H, K)$ show that $T^* \in B_{00}(K, H)$ and $\dim (\rm ran T) = \dim(\rm ran T^*)$. [$B_{00}(H, K)$ is the set of continuous finite rank operators]

First part is easy.

For second part of the question : ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3899920/if-t-in-mathcalb-00-mathcalh-mathcalh-show-dim-operatorname)) and ([2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693388/why-does-dim-range-t-dim-range-t)) and ([3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717604/does-a-clean-proof-exist-of-why-mbox-dim-ranget-mbox-dim-ranget?rq=1)) 'explains' why $\dim(\rm ran(T))=\dim(\rm ran(T^∗))$ but none is understandable:

In **1**, how $H=\ker T\oplus (\ker T)^\perp$ implies $\dim(\mathop{\rm ran}T^*)\,=\, \dim(\mathop{\rm ran}T)\,$?

In **2**, $\operatorname{dim} \operatorname{null} T + \operatorname{dim} (\operatorname{null} T)^\perp = \operatorname{dim} V$ implies $\dim(\mathop{\rm ran}T^*)\,=\, \dim(\mathop{\rm ran}T)\,$?

In **3**, how $T^*P=T^*$ implies $\operatorname{rank}T^*\le \operatorname{rank}P=\operatorname{rank}T$?

Could someone explain **one** of the questions in the other answers I mentioned above, **or** give a different easy to understand proof for the main question?

Comment: Is the dimension here the Hilbert space dimension (cardinality of an ONB) or the algebraic dimension (cardinality of a Hamel basis)?

Comment: @MaoWao, H is a Hilbert space and dimension is defined on this sentence "An operator Τ on H has finite rank if ran Τ is finite dimensional".

Comment: So $B_{00}$ stands for the finite rank operators? You should put that into your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $T \in \mathcal{B}_{00}(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{H})$, show $\dim(\operatorname{ran}(T)) = \dim(\operatorname{ran}(T^*))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3899920/if-t-in-mathcalb-00-mathcalh-mathcalh-show-dim-operatorname)

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with a simple lemma:

> **Lemma**: Let $H$ and $K$ be Hilbert spaces and let $T$ be a continuous linear function from $H$ to $K$. Then $\rm ran \,T^* \subseteq (\ker T)^\perp$.

**Proof**: Given any $y \in K$, we have, for all $x \in \ker T$,
$$ \langle T^*y, x \rangle_H = \langle y, Tx \rangle_K =  \langle y, 0 \rangle_K =0 $$
So, for all $y \in K$, $T^*y \in (\ker T)^\perp$. So, we have that $\rm ran \,T^* \subseteq (\ker T)^\perp$. $\square$

Now, let $B_{00}(H, K)$ be the set of continuous finite rank operators. Let us prove

> If $T \in B_{00}(H, K)$, then $T^* \in B_{00}(K, H)$ and $\dim (\rm ran \, T) = \dim(\rm ran T^*)$.

**Proof**: Let $T$ be a continuous linear function from $H$ to $K$. It is easy to see that
$T|_{(\ker T)^\perp)}: (\ker T)^\perp \rightarrow \rm ran \, T$ is a isomorphism.
So,
$$ \dim (\ker T)^\perp  = \dim \rm ran \, T $$
Using the lemma above, we have
$$ \dim \rm ran \, T^* \leq \dim (\ker T)^\perp  = \dim \rm ran \, T $$

So, we have $\dim \rm ran \, T^* \leq \dim \rm ran \, T $. Applying it to $T^{*}$, we have $\dim \rm ran \, T = \dim \rm ran \, T^{**} \leq \dim \rm ran \, T^* $. So $\dim \rm ran \, T =  \dim \rm ran \, T^* $.

So, we have proved that, for any $T$ be a continuous linear function from $H$ to $K$, $\dim \rm ran \, T =  \dim \rm ran \, T^* $.

Now, if $T \in B_{00}(H, K)$, then $\dim (\rm ran \, T)$ is finite. So $\dim (\rm ran \, T^*)$ is finite. So, $T^* \in B_{00}(K, H)$. $\square$

Comment: +1 Shouldn't this be the proof that row rank = column rank for matrices?

Comment: @Gribouillis Yes, if $H$ and $K$ are finite dimensional spaces, the proof above shows that row rank = column rank for matrices.